# createsuperuser is behaving strangely

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using django 1.3 on MacBook(OSX 10.7.5)
Inside my virtualenv I am trying to do

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get back

```
Username (Leave blank to use '****'):^M
```

If I hit enter it gets stuck with ^M (This happens irrespective of whether I leave blank or put an username. Any thought?

Comment: You have wrong `TERM` environment variable in your console.

Comment: Thanks. I rebooted, and that resolved the issue. It was some silly problem that messed up my setup. thanks again